# Are these words Isthlal and Kufr

Tags: fatwa, kuffar

**when someone for example say these kind of phrases does it mean that he thinks that what he is doing Halal ,and does he become a kafr just for saying it **

1. when someone is drinking and say " I should drink more tonight"
2. when someone is doing Haram as stealing something and he says that it is work

> does a person be Kafr just for saying these sort of phrases or it is about thinking  that it is Halal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something Haram doesn't make people Kuffar. You don't know when they will make Tawba, or when God will lead them to the right way.

Saying about a person a Kafer is not an easy thing, due to this [site](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=52765): if one says about his brother a Kafer, then he is too. (I know this is outsinde the question, just for clarification).

However a person doing something Haram, and saying it is Halal, it is either ways. The first one isthat he doesn't know Halal from Haram and needs someone to sit with him and teach him, or he is really leaded by Satan and needs someone to take by his hand and make him do Tawba, after being convinced because

```
"There is no compulsion in religion" (2:256).
```

As a conclusion if a person is making something Haram, so we can say he is making something Kufur, but we can't say Kafir about him, especially if he still believes that there is no God but Allah.

Edits:

اذا قال أحدهم أن السرقة لا عيب فيها، بينما كلنا يعلم أن السرقة حرام، فهذا العمل يكسب عليه سيئات، وعليك بنصحه. فإن لم ينتصح فدعه لله.
ولكن لا نقول أن هذا العمل كفر أو لا، الا اذا كان في العمل إشراك لله، ولكن نقول حلال أو حرام.

This [reference](http://www.tawhed.ws/r1?i=4781&x=jzoyrjz8) has the thing s mentioned above about saying that robbery is Haram but not Kufr.

Comment: meant when something Haram , and he knows it is Haram , but let's say if you asked about it  , they'd say its something Normal or it's non your job

Comment: Yes, even though you should explain this to him, and say why is this thing Haram.

Comment: nope let's I said "it's okay to steal something from your dad" , but didn't say it is HALAL , is that the same saying it is Halal or not

Comment: this is what I mean , I am asking if this deed Kufr or not , but I am not looking to say for someone that he is a kafr , because I know it is not an easy thing to judge , answer me in Arabic

Comment: because I'd understand better than you answer in English

Comment: I edited my answer check if that works, don't hesitate to ask plz

Comment: شكرا الان فهمت ذلك

Comment: can you please give me link of this fatwa if you have